# Fullcalendar display the count of events per day

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, events, fullcalendar

I using the FullCalendar and i would like display the count of events per day in all views for each days.

Example :

```
<div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
```

Change to :

```
<div class="fc-day-count">X</div>
<div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
```

Please find a screenshoot as example:
[link](http://postimg.org/image/l7hj5nkmr/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit. The question is too vague.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply, please find a link to a screenshoot as example :
[link](http://postimg.org/image/l7hj5nkmr/)

Comment: What technology are you using?  JSP? Only javascript? You can set tags on your question with the technologies used. Like that, more people with the right skills will find your question and can answer it. But with the link, now the functional aspect is very clear. :)  +1

Comment: I just add tags, i use Javascript, Jquery, and php

Comment: id also like to know how to show no of events in every cell in the day view, instead of show the events themeselves (which is the default) and im loading events from an aax source

Comment: The example link doesn't work anymore :-(

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps someone but don't know if it's the exact answer you're looking for.

To get the number of events that occur on a day you can use the following code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', function(eventObj){
    if (eventObj.start.isSame('2014-11-21')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}).length;
```

As per fullcalendar documentation you can search for events with a filter function [clientEvents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/).

The if statement in the function compares dates using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) which is included in fullcalendar 2.0

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I changed `.isSame()` to a simple `==` to compare each event's moment's year to the currently displayed year, quickly counting the number of events showing in listYear view.

Comment: @itnAAnti Glad it helped, I went through a lot of pain with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample in Month View** EventsPerDay variable gives count

```
 eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 
 $(element).each(function () { $(this).addClass('dateClass-' + event.start.getDate().toString()); $(this).attr('date-num', event.start.getDate().toString()); });
                   if (view.name == "month") {
                       // $('.shifts,.tasks,.shiftOut,.shiftIn').hide();
                       var CellDates = [];
                       var EventDates = [];
                       var EventCount = 0, i = 0;

                       $('.fc-view-month').find('.fc-day-number').each(function () {
                           CellDates[i] = $(this).text();
                           //                           alert( $(this).text());
                           i++;
                       });

                       for (j = 0; j < CellDates.length; j++) {

                           EventsPerDay = $(".fc-view-month>div>.dateClass-" + CellDates[j]).length;}}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer, but it take a lot of ressource (CPU) with a lot of events more than 800 events for one month. So i have edit my php script and i pass in the json source file the number of events per day.

Answer (score 0):

I added a line to fullcalendar.js in the method named

**function fetchEventSource(source, fetchID)**:

```
    function fetchEventSource(source, fetchID) {
    _fetchEventSource(source, function(events) {
        if (fetchID == currentFetchID) {
            if (events) {

                if (options.eventDataTransform) {
                    events = $.map(events, options.eventDataTransform);
                }
                if (source.eventDataTransform) {
                    events = $.map(events, source.eventDataTransform);
                }
                // TODO: this technique is not ideal for static array event sources.
                //  For arrays, we'll want to process all events right in the beginning, then never again.

                for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
                    events[i].source = source;
                    normalizeEvent(events[i]);
                }
                cache = cache.concat(events);
            }
            pendingSourceCnt--;
            if (!pendingSourceCnt) {
                reportEvents(cache);
            }
        }

        // add this next line here to dump the running count
        $("#someElement").html("There are " + cache.length + " events scheduled for this view");
    });
}
```

This has the net effect of leveraging what fullcalendar is already doing. You can then save yourself the extra network call on the database.